# Нужны ли запятые в моём предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

В предложении: «Ему будет трудно все выслушать да еще и уловить и понять» нужны ли вообще запятые. Склоняюсь, что нет. Или это как из Пушкина: «Татьяна верила преданьям простонародной старины, и снам, и карточным гаданьям, и предсказаниям луны»....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не ставится запятая перед союзом *да и* в следующих случаях, когда он употреблён в соединительном значении (*Вот пошёл он в лес по орехи да и заблудился*).

В предложениях с уточняющими, пояснительными и присоединительными членами используются запятая и тире (*Работу можно было давно уже сделать, и даже лучше*; Нет, я его [домового] не видал, да его и видеть нельзя).

*Ему будет трудно всё выслушать, да ещё и уловить и понять.* (Два союза во второй части не является повторением: последний, даже при желании, нельзя заменить запятой).

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос распадается на две части: нужна ли запятая перед "да ещё" и нужна ли запятая между "(и) уловить(,) и понять".

- Запятая перед "да ещё" ставится, если это словосочетание означает "к
  тому же", то есть содержит дополнительное замечание или разъяснение к
  сказанному ранее:

  > Вы уже, конечно, обратили внимание на то, что боец последнего года
  > службы Иван Чонкин был маленького роста, кривоногий, да еще и с
  > красными ушами (Войнович).

  Запятая перед "да ещё" не ставится, если это словосочетание означает присоединение наподобие "и":

  > Алёше стало удивительно ощущать себя посреди их вопиющей наготы
  > спелёнатым в шинельку да ещё и в мундир... (О. Павлов).

  В вашем случае, на мой взгляд, возможны оба варианта.
- Запятая "(и) уловить(,) и понять" также может ставиться либо не
  ставиться в зависимости от того, какое смысловое членение подразумевает
  автор:
  ***да ещё / и уловить, и понять*** (повторяющийся союз "и", запятая нужна)
  или
  ***да ещё и / уловить и понять*** (одиночный союз "и",
  запятая не нужна).

Comment: то есть по идее одна запятая, перед «да еще и»...

Comment: @flossyU я склоняюсь к такому же варианту.